# How can I detect manually modified Nuget content in my solution?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

In my project I use a number of Nuget packages (javascript, typescript, other stuff). I'm afraid that while working on it I modified some content which was initially created by the package manager. So there are some questions:

- how can I detect files received from Nuget that have been modified by me, e.g. those that don't match with the initial version of file rendered by Nuget?
- how can I restore modified Nuget files to their initial versions?
- how can I prevent this in the future, e.g. get some notification like "this content originates from Nuget, don't modify it!"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I detect files received from Nuget that have been modified by me, e.g. those that don't match with the initial version of file rendered by Nuget?

AFAIK, there is not a intuitive way to detect files received from Nuget that have been modified, but I would like provide you a workaround to detect those modified files. You can use the below command line in the Package Manager Console:

```
Update-Package –reinstall packagename
```

If you have made some modification on that package before using this command, you will get a prompt: **Skipping filename' because it was modified.** in the Package Manager Console window.

[image]

> how can I restore modified Nuget files to their initial versions?

You can also use the method which I mentioned before, you can notice that there is an another prompting: "**File is already exist in the project, Do you want to overwrite it**". If you enter Y or A, all the modified files will restore to their initial versions, or you can uninstall the package and reinstall it(need to delete those modification file manually)

> how can I prevent this in the future, e.g. get some notification like "this content originates from Nuget, don't modify it!"

If you want to prevent the file from being modified, you can consider marking the files as read-only or something - any files that are pulled down i.e. source file or content should be considered read-only IMO.

[image]